# How to write a code test that covers const in javascript files

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Example I have a file called `apiConfig.js`

With a simply line of code:

```
const apiVersion = 'v1';
```

If I create a file called `apiConfig.test.js`

How do I write the code to test the const?

Comment: Export the const. Import into the test. Then expect that its value is what you want.

Comment: Consider reading their [getting started](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started) guide?

Comment: If your ORG uses SonarQube you understand code coverage and I am trying to cover as much code as possible.  I will read the getting started guide, evolutionbox.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a design issue than mechanics.

You should ask yourself why you want to test const.

I like [the advice from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593246/for-unit-tests-is-there-a-hackish-way-to-change-the-value-of-a-const-variable) to split your code into two parts - one that is parameterized and can be tested properly, and the other which encodes the "constness".